# how to redirect to mobile site while still leaving the option open to view desktop version

Tags: php, mobile, cross-browser

I am looking for a way to redirect mobile browsers to a mobile specific version of my site.  My issue is that I also need to provide a link in the mobile version that allows users to view the desktop site if they wish.

I could redirect based on browser, but then linking to the main site will only loop back to the mobile.

I can't use a session variable, as I have a log in system that destroys the session data and so cause the user to return to the mobile site on logout.

I thought of using a redirect script as the index page to a separe desktop home page, but this would require restructuring my desktop site and play havoc with cms.  I am unsure also what effect this would have on search engine ratings.

Can anyone thing of any other good way of handling this issue or will I have to bite the bullet and restructure my desktop site?

Comment: Why not just use @media queries?

Comment: set a cookie if the user clicks to view the desktop version. check for it before the automatic redirects

Comment: One option would be to just use a GET parameter, `?forcedesktopversion=1` – if that is set, refrain from automatic redirect to mobile version. (But don’t forget you have to dynamically append that to all internal links.)

Comment: @CBroe Yeah, I thought about that as well, but that won't save if they leave and come back (close + reopen), and like you said would have to be appended when they click links

Comment: To detect the user agent and redirecting, I suggest take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698454/mobile-site-redirect-to-desktop-version-using-htaccess?rq=1), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528254/how-to-redirect-desktop-users-away-from-mobile-site-with-php?rq=1) and [detectmobilebrowsers.com](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set a cookie (not a session cookie) when the user forces to see the desktop version sending a get paramter and then check its presence in the block where you detect the browser to redirect to the mobile version.
Basically (pseudo-code):

```
# set the cookie if the user want to see the desktop version
if GET[force-desktop-version]
   set_cookie(force-desktop-version = 1)
end

# check the cookie and the browser before redirecting
if NOT get_cookie(force-desktop-version) and mobile_browser_used 
   redirect_to the_mobile_version
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope! there is a pretty simple way around this. You can check the last page the user visited in this way:
`document.referrer`

 Send the user to the mobile page if the referrer is any website other than the mobile page, if it is the mobile page, then you know that they clicked a 'redirect to desktop version' link.

Comment: Nice idea, but then the user would have to re-force the desktop version every time he comes through an inbound link.

Comment: Good idea, in my case the required re-force of the desktop version would be an issue, but I can certainly see scenarios where this would be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well on sign out page (where the session data is destroyed), just check if $_SESSION['mobile'] or some variable name is set to 1 or not. If it's set to 1, then start session again and set only this value to 1 in new session before redirecting to homepage.